# Retrieve image files in the storage/app folder using laravel restful API

Tags: php, ajax, rest, laravel

I have created a restful API using laravel, the API feeds a mobile client that uses ajax to retrieve and send data to/from the API. I am able to send base64 encoded images to the API where i decode and save them in storage/app folder. Now i am trying to create a route that will allow the client to retrieve those images to append on the interface. i have route defined as

```
route::get('api/v1/logo/{event_id}', 'EventController@getLogo')
```

it gets an event_id from the ajax call which it uses to search the image required and send it back. In the controller i have a function

```
$this->logoDirectory = 'logo' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  public function getLogo(Event $event )
{

    $path = storage_path('app\logo\default.png');
    if( ! empty( $event ) && Storage::exists(  $this->logoDirectory .$event->id.".$event->logo_ext))
    {
        $path = storage_path() .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $this->logoDirectory .$event->id.".".$event->logo_ext;
    }

    $file = File::get( $path );
    $type = File::mimeType( storage_path() .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$path );



    $response = response()->make( $file, 200 );
    $response->header( 'Content-Type', $type );
    return $response;
}
```

note that all images are stored using their respective event id as the name, and the file extension is extracted upon storage and save in the database as logo_ext. can someone help out here. Thank you

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? So you see error message?

Comment: @Andrej. it varies but at the moment i am getting "Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\finfo_file()"

Comment: Shouldn't be here $this->logoDirectory .$event->id.".JPEG"?

Comment: this is the error now File does not exist at path "serverpath\storage\app\logo\." it appears that it is not getting the file name ($event->id) and the extension ($event->logo_ext)

Comment: I am in same kind of situation ,I think the server is hosted in public directory and the storage folder is outside that directory that why it doesn't recognize that route